# Fetch Sub for Cognito user in Python Code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using CloudFormation Template to auto tag resources in AWS, Script [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/)

Below is lambda function which I am using to tag resources, I am new to AWS and I have not idea of Python.

Current it is tagging like

Owner ------------- CognitoIdentityCredentials // it should be replaced with user unique id i.e sub
 PrincipalId ------- :CognitoIdentityCredentials

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 import json
 import boto3
 import logging
 import time
 import datetime

 logger = logging.getLogger()
 logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  def lambda_handler(event, context):
#logger.info('Event: ' + str(event))
#print('Received event: ' + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

ids = []

try:
    region = event['region']
    detail = event['detail']
    eventname = detail['eventName']
    arn = detail['userIdentity']['arn']
    principal = detail['userIdentity']['principalId']
    userType = detail['userIdentity']['type']

    if userType == 'IAMUser':
        user = detail['userIdentity']['userName'] //here i want replace with sub

    else:
        user = principal.split(':')[1]


    logger.info('principalId: ' + str(principal))
    logger.info('region: ' + str(region))
    logger.info('eventName: ' + str(eventname))
    logger.info('detail: ' + str(detail))

    if not detail['responseElements']:
        logger.warning('Not responseElements found')
        if detail['errorCode']:
            logger.error('errorCode: ' + detail['errorCode'])
        if detail['errorMessage']:
            logger.error('errorMessage: ' + detail['errorMessage'])
        return False

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

    if eventname == 'CreateVolume':
        ids.append(detail['responseElements']['volumeId'])
        logger.info(ids)

    elif eventname == 'RunInstances':
        items = detail['responseElements']['instancesSet']['items']
        for item in items:
            ids.append(item['instanceId'])
        logger.info(ids)
        logger.info('number of instances: ' + str(len(ids)))

        base = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids)

        #loop through the instances
        for instance in base:
            for vol in instance.volumes.all():
                ids.append(vol.id)
            for eni in instance.network_interfaces:
                ids.append(eni.id)

    elif eventname == 'CreateImage':
        ids.append(detail['responseElements']['imageId'])
        logger.info(ids)

    elif eventname == 'CreateSnapshot':
        ids.append(detail['responseElements']['snapshotId'])
        logger.info(ids)
    else:
        logger.warning('Not supported action')

    if ids:
        for resourceid in ids:
            print('Tagging resource ' + resourceid)
        ec2.create_tags(Resources=ids, Tags=[{'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': user}, {'Key': 'PrincipalId', 'Value': principal}])

    logger.info(' Remaining time (ms): ' + str(context.get_remaining_time_in_millis()) + '\n')
    return True
except Exception as e:
    logger.error('Something went wrong: ' + str(e))
    return False
```

I want in place of username, I want to felow Cognito user Sub. Can anyone suggest me how to do? My [Repo](https://github.com/sparshgoyal024/TestAWS) for reference

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_id

Comment: i tried to integrate both code but not working, in Logins={  cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_123456789 } what to put here, I am putting like this

Comment: Are you able to successfully generate the tokens?

Comment: yes, I am generating in my application, like access key, secret key, I know i have to give ( 'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>': '<JWT ID Token> ) but tokens I generate in my HTML application, how do i integrate here, or can we fetch that here somehow?

Comment: You need the ID token to get the sub. Maybe create an API to supply this information to your python?

Comment: id_token = event["id_token"] will this help? I got this from some other answer, unintended block error i am getting after this

Comment: It won't help unless your event has the id_token.

Comment: you can refer my code from here https://github.com/sparshgoyal024/TestAWS